# Does std::string works only with 'std::cin' in c++

Tags: c++, scanf, cin, stdstring

I've recently learnt about `std::substr()` by searching on Google. I saw a code something like this:

```
std::string s = "This is an example string";
std::string s1 = s.substr(11, 7);
std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
```

Now if I try to take input using `scanf()` function (instead of using `std::cin`), the program crashes during runtime. Doesn't `std::string` support using `scanf()` function?

Comment: The question isn't very clear to me. Are you trying to get input from a string, for from the standard input, and what does substr have to do with your question? Basically I need to know what you are trying to do, then I could say how to do it.

Comment: `substr` doesn't work on `cin`, it works on `string`.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h/31816096#31816096)

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: 'scanf()' with an unbounded `%s` or `%[` is as dangerous as `gets()` (for the same reason).  And neither of them want a `std::string` as the corresponding argument (they take a `char *`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf()` belongs to a family of C functions that, being part of the C language rather than C++, offers no direct support for `std::string` and works instead with null terminated character strings.

If you are using C++, you should generally prefer `std::string` over null terminated terminated character strings and [the input/output library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) over `printf()`/`scanf()` library functions.